# How to detect databases using jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, service-discovery

Using JDBC, looking to construct utility that will look at our network and return all the databases found. I have identified JavaDB, MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle and Access databases. The idea is you would find the database you want, select it and provide credentials. The point is you may not know a database exists before you see it and the discovery will institute a measure of control.

What I am looking for is a common way to discover all types of databases across the network.

```
public class ListSchemas {
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet schemas = meta.getSchemas();
```

works for some databases. Thoughts?

Comment: You want to research [Service discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery).

Comment: One of the ideas shared by a colleague is to use a network sniffer, detect and store the results ....

Comment: http://www.mytechnotes.biz/2013/01/what-is-jndi-spi-cci-ldap-and-jca.html provides an interesting overview.

Comment: @BobParis the domain name has changed  
https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2013/01/what-is-jndi-spi-cci-ldap-and-jca.html